# Azure SAML2 login system issue

Tags: laravel, azure, saml-2.0

Short description:

Im using laravel application which already has system for logging in with microsoft account. That system works, but this is the first time im working on it, and i can not establish locally that users can sign in with their microsoft account into the application. Because system in the application works, and i get error when logging in, the issue must be in my configuration at Azure portal.

My configuration is as following:
I have created tenant and registered app in it. My SAML config is as following:

Entity ID: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/saml2
Reply URL (Assertion Consumer Service URL): https://sts.windows.net/tenant-id/

In my .env i have set following values:

```
 AZURE_AD_CALLBACK_URL=/login/microsoft/callback
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID=id-of-the-application-in-tenant
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET=tenant-secret-key
SAML2_AZURE_SAML_ENABLED=true
SAML2_AZURE_IDP_SSO_URL="https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/saml2"
SAML2_AZURE_IDP_ENTITYID="https://sts.windows.net/tenant-id/"
SAML2_AZURE_IDP_x509="tenant-id"
SAML2_AZURE_SP_ENTITYID="https://some-app.com/"
```

I get following error after entering my credentials:
AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'https://someapp/' was not found in the directory 'tenant-id'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

I have added user to the application, which i use to test login, so this error is totally confusing for me.

I dont know if i provided all neccessary info, but if some missing i will provide them.

I hope someone knows what is wrong with the configuration

Answer (score 0):

The tenant id is a GUID. Have you used this or are you using the "tenant-id" string?

Also, the ACS is an endpoint in your application - not an Azure URL.

Comment: I had __Host- prefix on my cookies, and same_site was set to 'strict' - after removing prefixes and setting same_site to 'lax', login worked.